# String.format is creating error

Tags: java, string, string-formatting

I am a beginner in coding, and I don't know why this code is not working. Ps. it is not showing any error in eclipse while I was typing, but when I run it it is not running. This only happened when I use `String.format()`, When I was using `StringBuilder` to return in the `toString` method, the codes run just fine.

```
class Dog {

    private int age;
    private String name;

    public Dog(String name, int age) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;

    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("my name is %s and im %d years old", name, age);
    }
}

class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Dog dog1 = new Dog("bob", 6);
        System.out.println(dog1);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by it is not running?

Comment: @benson Please accept the answer which helped you most in solving your problem. It helps future readers. If the answers weren't helpful leave comments below them. So the poster can update them accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `%s` for `name` and `%d` for `age` you have them the wrong way around.

---

On a side note, you should also add `@Override` to your `toString()` method.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the use of `String.format()` parameters [here](https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples).

- `%d` applies to **byte, short, int, long, bigint**.
- `%s` to **any type**

---

As `name` is a `String` you have to use `%s`, as `age` is an `int` you can use both `%s` or `%d`. So the statements

```
return String.format("my name is %s and im %d years old", name, age);
```

AND

```
return String.format("my name is %s and im %s years old", name, age);
```

are both valid.

Answer (score 0):

Change that line to the following:

```
return String.format("my name is %s and im %d years old", name, age);
```

Since `%s` is used for strings and `%d` is used for numbers.